# Situations where CakePHP 2 might not populate `created` or `modified` fields on a table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a legacy application in CakePHP 2.4.4

I have added a new database table and added `created` and `modified` fields to it, both of which are `DATETIME`. Database is MySQL.

I've done a lot of work with Cake (2 and 3) before and always found that these fields will be updated automatically when records are created/modified. It even mentions this in the documentation for Cake 2: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#using-created-and-modified

When I save or edit a record, `created` (or `modified` if editing) is populated with `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Why could this be? I don't even know where to begin to look for this as I've never known it to occur.

I am not doing anything in my Controller or Model to "unset" these fields either.

Structure of my table is as follows. I've also tried changing `Null` to `NO` on `created` and `modified` - same result.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE tags;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am saving edited data as follows:

```
$this->Tag->save( $this->request->data )
```

If I `var_dump($this->request->data)` it looks like this:

```
array(2) { ["Save"]=> string(6) "Update" ["Tag"]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["title"]=> string(6) "France" } }
```

Model (`app/Model/Tag.php`) - about as basic as you can get:

```
class Tag extends AppModel {
}
```

Comment: Please show the schema definition for your table. Eg, `DESCRIBE your_table` in MySQL.

Comment: Or show us the export structure of the table from phpmyadmin.

Comment: Ok, I've posted it.

Comment: Did you try to set null to be `NO`?

Comment: Another thing, could you submit `Tag` model code?

Comment: @SaidbakR I've submitted the code I'm using to save it and the `var_dump`'d output. If I set null to `NO` the result is the same (it saves as `0000-`...)

Comment: Well try to use [whitelist](https://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#$whitelist) property in the model and assign created and modified as whitelist. @Andy

Comment: Also, checkout the `models/App.php` if it is found, it may be have some code conflicts with your attend.

Comment: As a little test try to extend `Tag` model from `Model` instead of `AppModel`. @Andy

Comment: The string `0000-00-00 00:00:00` (zero value) means invalid format in MySQL. Check any behaviors attached to AppModel. Also, any loaded plugins that might affect saving to database.

Comment: Extending `Model` instead of `AppModel` gives an Internal Server Error. The whitelist property made no difference. @InigoFlores how would I "check any behaviours attached to AppModel"? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Look for something similar to `public $actsAs = array('BehaviorName')` in `AppModel.php`. Plugins are loaded in `/app/Config/bootstrap.php` with `CakePlugin::load('PluginName')`. If you have `CakePlugin::loadAll()` it will load everything inside `/app/Plugin/`. In this case, let us know what's in there.